# Packet loss test with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, packet-loss

Is there a way to check packet loss from client side with javascipt by using ajax, xmlHttpRequest or other method?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I know its possible in java but I don't think it is possible javascript

Answer (score 3):

**HTTP** is based on **TCP** which guarantees delivery of data. Server and client should be aware of an issue that would cause some data to be missed. The TCP layer would retransmit the data as needed until it is complete.

Packet loss and out of order delivery are not uncommon on the internet since there is no rule that says routers must forward all packets but TCP automatically corrects for those issues.

unfortunatley there is nothing you can do about it using javascript .